# Keep getting a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting a Run-time error '13' type mismatch and I do not know why.  I have a sheet (Sheet1) that has data on it that I want to copy to another sheet (Sheet 6) only where info in a column has USA.  It also clears the other sheet (Sheet 6) data before it does this is I will be updating the information on Sheet1 every week so sheet 6 needs to update also. I can not find out why I am getting a type mismatch on my if statement.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("Sheet6").Activate
ActiveSheet.Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


End With


For i = 2 To a
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
     If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = "USA" Then
     ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Copy

     Worksheets("Sheet6").Activate
     With Worksheets("Sheet6")
     b = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     End With
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate



     End If

     Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: This is wierd: `IsNumeric (b = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)` What are you trying to do here? `b` isn't defined. `b = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` will return `True` or `False` and `Isnumeric` will always be `True` (as `True` and `False` both are Numeric being that they are boolean). So this entire line just says `True` and doesn't do anything with it. You can just comment out that line as it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Then here `ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).Select` but again the variable `b` isn't defined. Remove that `b+` since it's superfluous at best, and error causing at worst. (or change that `b` to an `a` to use the variable you are iterating in your `For` loop).

Comment: Just make the sheet references part of the object and avoid .Activate... e.g., *Worksheets("Sheet6").Activate
ActiveSheet.Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents* becomes *Worksheets("Sheet6").Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents*.  You don't need to activate a sheet before using it in the With statement either.

Comment: It shows me in debug that it is throwing the error on  If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = "USA" Then

Comment: ISNumeric() should not be there only b=......

Comment: What's the value of `i` when it blows up? And what's the value of that cell at `(i, 5)`? If the value is a cell error e.g. `#REF!` or `#VALUE!`, then you can't coerce it into a string to compare with `"USA"` - you need to verify whether `IsError(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value)` before you can safely treat that cell value as a string (or any other type).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to convert your cell data to string (CSTR) before evaluation:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("Sheet6").Activate
ActiveSheet.Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


End With


For i = 2 To a
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
If CSTR(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value) = "USA" Then 
     ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Copy

     Worksheets("Sheet6").Activate
     With Worksheets("Sheet6")
     b = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     End With
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate



     End If

     Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```